# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment when swapping values

Tags: python

I am writing a simple sort program in python and encounter this error. I want to swap list elements but it returns an error. I am attaching the error and program in question below.

```
list[i+1] = list[i]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Code:

```
def my_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value=list[index]
        i=index-1
        while i>=0:
            if value<list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i]=value
                i=i-1
            else:
                break
    return

    input_list=eval(input("Enter list items"))
    my_sort(input_list)
    print(input_list)
```

Comment: Don't use the word list. Could you put the code correctly indented?

Comment: Please don't *ever* call a variable "list". "list" is a builtin type. Now you can't convert it to from a tuple to a list with `list(thing)`.

Comment: *Why in the world* would you use eval? A much easier solution would be to split by `,` and then strip extra spaces.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Evaluating "1,2,3" results in `(1, 2, 3)`, a `tuple`. As you've discovered, tuples are immutable. Convert to a list before processing.

Comment: I am new to python. Can you please help me how to convert tuple to list? Or better, how to have user input a list directly?

Comment: To input a list directly, surround the sequence with square brackets: "[1,2,3]". To convert to a list, pass it to the list constructor: `L = list(S)`.

Comment: The final missing piece in the answer is after processing list convert it back with `S = tuple(L)`

Answer (score 8):

or simply assign the whole tuple itself, instead of changing elements inside tuple.

example: want to add 'count' to 1st element of the 'i-th' tuple :

```
tup[i] = (tup[i][0] + count, tup[i][1])
```

Comment: I do believe this should be the right answer as it is the most simple and direct solution without the need of converting data ..

Answer (score 4):

To anyone googling this error: check for unwanted commas in your code.
For example,

```
arr = np.zeros(n),
arr[i] = something
```

will throw this error.