# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment - open(index)

Tags: python

I am new in Python and I'm having some difficulties. I am trying this code:

```
import os

ListB=[]
for x in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\.....\\......\\filesC'):

    fullPath = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\......\\.......\\filesC' + '\\' + x 
    ListB.append(fullPath)  
File_a=open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\......\\Object.txt').readlines()

FullFilesList=()

index=0;
for x in ListB:

    FullFilesList[index]=open(x).readlines() + File_a
    index+=1
```

I am getting this error:

```
FullFilesList[index]=open(x).readlines() + File_a
```

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

I am sorry if my question is not smart enough, but I am used to code in C#. If someone can give me an advise how to fix this I will be greatfull. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. Here `FullFilesList` is a tuple.So when you try to assign a value at `index` it will rise `TypeError`. If you really want to do that convert `FullFilesList` to a list first,  then mutate it and convert back to tuple again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `FullFilesList` was a list as its name implies, you're handling it in an unsupported manner. As a rule of thumb, don't index. Assigning indices that don't exist is an `IndexError` for a list, but an insertion for a dictionary. For tuples it's simply impossible. Either use `append`:

```
FullFilesList = list()   # or just []
for x in ListB:
    FullFilesList.append(open(x).readlines() + File_a)
```

Or build the whole list in one step with a comprehension:

```
FullFilesList = [open(x).readlines() + File_a
                 for x in ListB]
```

This tends to be easier to reason about, as there are no intermediate states of the list and we don't need to track its length (use `len(FullFilesList)` if you need that).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `FullFilesList = ()`, you're declaring a tuple (try typing `type(FullFilesList)` to verify). Tuples are immutable in Python, so you can't change FullFilesList in your for loop (you can only create a new tuple and make FullFilesList refer to that new tuple). See other posts such as this one: [TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment when swapping values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735838/typeerror-tuple-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-when-swapping-values) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When the Python interpreter runs the line `FullFilesList=()`, it creates a new empty tuple and binds the name `FullFilesList` to it. Tuples are immutable, they can't be changed after they're created, so you can't make much use of that variable. Instead, it sounds like you wanted a list. To create an empty list, use the same syntax you used when you created the list for `ListB`: `FullFilesList=[]`

You'll run into another issue though. When you want to add your values to `FullFilesList`, you're assigning them to an index that doesn't exist yet. That won't work. If you want to append each value to the end of the list, use the `list.append` method instead (again, like you did with `ListB` in your first loop).

There are also some minor things that could be improved in your code. Two I'll point out are naming conventions and `with` statements. Python convention for regular variable names is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores`. Limit `CapitalizedNames` for classes, unless you're following an existing API that uses some other convention. You can read more about Python style suggestions in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Note that that's the style guide for the Python interpreter itself, not all Python projects follow it for their own code (but many do!).

My other suggestion has to do with making sure your files get closed after you're done with them. In your current code, you're often `open`ing a file, calling the `readlines` method on it and then dropping it without calling `close` on it. That will often work fine since the file object will be garbage collected and it will close as part of that process. But it's not guaranteed to work that way (the Python language does not make strong guarantees about when garbage collection will occur). A better approach is to ensure the file is closed yourself, using a `with` statement:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
# the file is closed automatically when you exit the with block (you can still use contents)
```